# How do i add separate Navbar in admin dashboard in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router

I have an application running fine with both admin part and the user part. Now the requirement is to separate the admin navbar to user navbar.

The navbar in here is currently showing in all the routes but i want it to be restricted from /admin/... routes.

My app.js file is as follows

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import AdminDasboard from "./components/Admin/AdminDasboard";
import AddCategory from "./components/Category/AddCategory";
import CategoryComponent from "./components/Category/CategoryComponent";
import UpdateCategory from "./components/Category/UpdateCategory";
import CookiesPolicy from "./components/CookiesPolicy";
import DataSafety from "./components/DataSafety";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import EditPost from "./components/Posts/EditPost";
import Post from "./components/Posts/Post";
import PrivacyPolicy from "./components/PrivacyPolicy";
import SinglePostComponent from "./components/SinglePostComponent";
import Blog from "./pages/Blog";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Javascript from "./pages/Interview Q/Javascript";
import Node from "./pages/Interview Q/Node";
import React from "./pages/Interview Q/ReactFile";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import NotFound from "./pages/NotFound";
import AdminHome from "./pages/PrivateRoutes/AdminHome";
import { PrivateRoute } from "./pages/PrivateRoutes/PrivateRoutes";
import Register from "./pages/Register";
import Write from "./pages/Write";

const App = () => {
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("light");
  const darkTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      mode: mode,
    },
  });
  return (
    <Router>
      <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
        <Box bgcolor={"background.default"} color={"text.primary"}>
          <Navbar // This is showing in all routes
            isAuth={isAuth}
            setIsAuth={setIsAuth}
            mode={mode}
            setMode={setMode}
          />
          <Routes>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/"
              element={
                <Home setIsAuth={setIsAuth} mode={mode} setMode={setMode} />
              }
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/posts/:id"
              setIsAuth={setIsAuth}
              element={<SinglePostComponent />}></Route>
            <Route path="/write" element={<Write isAuth={isAuth} />}></Route>
            <Route path="/blog" element={<Blog />}></Route>
            <Route
              path="/interview-qa/node-js-interview-questions"
              element={<Node />}></Route>
            <Route
              path="/interview-qa/react-js-interview-questions"
              element={<React />}></Route>
            <Route
              path="/interview-qa/js-interview-questions"
              element={<Javascript />}></Route>

            {/* static pages */}
            <Route path="/privacy-policy" element={<PrivacyPolicy />}></Route>
            <Route path="/cookies-policy" element={<CookiesPolicy />}></Route>
            <Route path="/data-policy" element={<DataSafety />}></Route>
            <Route
              path="/login"
              element={<Login setIsAuth={setIsAuth} />}></Route>
            <Route path="/register" element={<Register />}></Route>
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />

            {/* Admin Routes */}

            <Route path="/admin" element={<PrivateRoute />}> { /*need different Navbar for this route or no route at all for this but not the current Navbar */}
              <Route path="dashboard" element={<AdminDasboard />} />
              <Route path="posts" element={<Post />} />
              <Route path="posts/edit-post/:id" element={<EditPost />} />

              <Route path="categories" element={<CategoryComponent />} />

              <Route path="categories/add-category" element={<AddCategory />} />
              <Route
                path="categories/edit-category/:id"
                element={<UpdateCategory />}
              />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </Box>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I want the navbar to be different for the Admin part.

How can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a outer Route which only has the Navbar and all the routes which need a Navbar are nested inside it

```
return (
    <Router>
      <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
        <Box bgcolor={"background.default"} color={"text.primary"}>
          
          <Routes>
           <Route path="/" element={<Navbar // This is showing in all routes nested inside it
            isAuth={isAuth}
            setIsAuth={setIsAuth}
            mode={mode}
            setMode={setMode}
          />}> // This is what you add
            <Route
              exact
              path="/"
              element={
                <Home setIsAuth={setIsAuth} mode={mode} setMode={setMode} />
              }
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/posts/:id"
              setIsAuth={setIsAuth}
              element={<SinglePostComponent />}></Route>
            <Route path="/write" element={<Write isAuth={isAuth} />}></Route>
            <Route path="/blog" element={<Blog />}></Route>
            <Route
              path="/interview-qa/node-js-interview-questions"
              element={<Node />}></Route>
            <Route
              path="/interview-qa/react-js-interview-questions"
              element={<React />}></Route>
            <Route
              path="/interview-qa/js-interview-questions"
              element={<Javascript />}></Route>

            {/* static pages */}
            <Route path="/privacy-policy" element={<PrivacyPolicy />}></Route>
            <Route path="/cookies-policy" element={<CookiesPolicy />}></Route>
            <Route path="/data-policy" element={<DataSafety />}></Route>
            <Route
              path="/login"
              element={<Login setIsAuth={setIsAuth} />}></Route>
            <Route path="/register" element={<Register />}></Route>
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />

          </Route> // The closing Route

            {/* Admin Routes */}

            <Route path="/admin" element={<PrivateRoute />}> { /*need different Navbar for this route or no route at all for this but not the current Navbar */}
              <Route path="dashboard" element={<AdminDasboard />} />
              <Route path="posts" element={<Post />} />
              <Route path="posts/edit-post/:id" element={<EditPost />} />

              <Route path="categories" element={<CategoryComponent />} />

              <Route path="categories/add-category" element={<AddCategory />} />
              <Route
                path="categories/edit-category/:id"
                element={<UpdateCategory />}
              />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </Box>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Router>
  );
```

Inside Navbar, now you will add Outlet where you want to show your components related to routes

// Inside Navbar.js

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

return (
//yourjsx
<Outlet/> // where you want to show your other components
)
```

Comment: When i do this, only navbar shows and nothing shows.

Comment: Edited answer, you also need to update Navbar.js

Comment: Yes, i added ```<Outlet />``` just like i added in ```<PrivateRoutes /> ``` and it works.